# Show alternate row colors using itemRenderers inside a List

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, itemrenderer

I have a `List` with an `itemRenderer` for displaying some data. Is there anyway i can set different styles or background colors for alternate rows?

My `List` is as follows :

```
<mx:List id="myList" alternatingItemColors="[0xffffff, 0xe4e4e4]"
    borderStyle="none"
    width="100%" height="100%" y="25"
    dataProvider="{infoColl}"
    styleName="listRendererStyle"
    itemRenderer="InfoRenderer"/>
```

Comment: My apologies. In my stylesheet, i had backgroundAlpha=0 for List that i didn't notice. That was the reason why `alternatingItemColors` for the simple list was not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code of `spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer` as a pattern. There is the following code to get background color (see in `updateDisplayList`):

```
        var alternatingColors:Array = getStyle("alternatingItemColors");

        if (alternatingColors && alternatingColors.length > 0)
        {
            // translate these colors into uints
            styleManager.getColorNames(alternatingColors);

            backgroundColor = alternatingColors[itemIndex % alternatingColors.length];
        }
```

But if you're using `spark.components.supportClasses.ItemRenderer` as a base class for your MXML renderer just set `autoDrawBackground` property to `true` and all the backgrounds will be drawn automatically.

Or read [the following documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html#WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7ffe) how to set `alternatingItemColors` style of the list to change the values of alternating rows.

Comment: [The same `alternatingItemColors` style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#style:alternatingItemColors).

Comment: My item renderer is an HBox? Do i need to implement some interface. I am getting an error saying styleManager is undefined. I am developing using Flex 3.

Comment: And what happened when you just set `alternatingItemColors` style for you list?

Comment: @Constantiner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1626/discussion-between-silverback-and-constantiner)

Answer (score 0):

For Flex3 or MX, you can use the `alternatingItemColors` style property to achieve this.

```
<mx:List id="myList" alternatingItemColors="[0xffffff, 0xe4e4e4]"/>
```

For Flex4 or Spark, you can look at @Constantiner's answer for a refined / deep level customization.

Guess the `alternatingItemColors` will do, and make sure you haven't turned the `backgroundAlpha` property of the `List` to 0 or a lesser value.